# How to use controls in freemarker template?

Tags: java, freemarker

I used to work with VS.NET but now I need to edit some java mvc page.

It is using freemarker templates - I understood how to get data to view, but how to post data back to server?

I need controller sample with a simple textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freemarker is a general purpose templating engine, so you have to use pure HTTP form submit.

Put in your template:

```
<form method="post" action="/process">
  <input type="text" name="myData" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Make sure that you have a server-side handler for `http://<domain>/process` URL.

Comment: is it possible to generate template from

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with forms (or whatever real-world Web page development), first you need to chose a Web Application Framework, like Stripes, Spring, etc. FreeMarker alone is just a bare-bone template engine. Forms, or any Web-related feature has to be provided by the framework, usually by framework-specific FreeMarker directives.